# How to do Multiple Left Join with Multiple Where in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, join

> $result = mysql_query("
>                         SELECT a.`user_id`, a.`user_name`, a.`cell_no`, a.`internet_package`, a.`activation_date`
>
> ```
>                   FROM `alepo_data` a
>                   LEFT JOIN `".$month2."` c ON c.`user_id` = a.`user_id`
>                   WHERE c.`user_id` IS NULL
>               ");
> ```

I have a query like above... Here I want to check for $month2. Now If I want to compare $month1 in the same way, then what would be the Query?

Note that, here $month1 or $month2 are SAME TYPE OF TABLE (with Same Table STRUCTURE) just holds different type of usage Data.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: If you have 12 identical tables for 12 different months of year, your database design is seriously flawed and your problem is a direct consequence of that.

Comment: I have no way to alter the Database. And, moreover, each month's Table is containing 2 crore Data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple joins by just adding the join to the ones you already have:

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.user_name,
    a.cell_no,
    a.internet_package,
    a.activation_date
FROM
    `alepo_data` a
    LEFT JOIN `month1Data` c1 ON c1.`user_id` = a.`user_id`
    LEFT JOIN `month2Data` c2 ON c2.`user_id` = a.`user_id`
WHERE
    c1.`user_id` IS NULL OR c2.`user_id` IS NULL
```

Note that, if your tables have the same (or even very similar) table structures, you probably can optimize your table structure. You might be able to fit everything into one table with a 'date' or 'month' column added. If not, you can probably still apply a [star schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema). If the tables are split because of performance reasons, have a look at [table partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/partitioning.html).

Comment: my month1Data and month2Data both Table have same Structure (same columns). I am understanding your query, but why "OR", and why not "AND"? Note that, `alepo_data` is the User Database. I want to check that which user have no usage data in month1Data and month2Data. Can you give me a solution that should I use "OR" or "AND" and should I use a "DISTINCT" before "SELECT a.user_id"???

Comment: The `OR` or `AND` depends on what you're trying to do. (I can't just guess that.) Do you want to find all users that have no data for one month (use `OR`) or for all months (use `AND`). `DISTINCT` (or a form of `GROUP BY`) is necessary if you have more than one row per user in the tables you `JOIN` with.

Comment: @Thomas, `alepo_data` is the Table that is containing User's Personal Information (User ID, Name, Mobile No, Internet Package that he is using, Activation Date of his Line etc). `month1Data` (for January with Same Structure) up to `month12Data` (December) are containing Usage Data of Each User per Month (User ID, Session Time, Upload, Download, Connection Time). I want to trace that, which Users has no use in `month1Data` and `month2Data`.

Comment: So, I used "SELECT a.`user_id`, a.`user_name`, a.`cell_no`, a.`internet_package`, a.`activation_date`
      FROM `alepo_data` a
      LEFT JOIN `".$month1Data."` c ON c.`user_id` = a.`user_id`
      LEFT JOIN `".$month2Data."` d ON d.`user_id` = a.`user_id`
      WHERE c.`user_id` IS NULL AND d.`user_id` IS NULL
     " ... Am I right? Please tell me... Please